# How to store access tokens in NodeJs for future calls to an API?

Tags: javascript, api, https

I have written a program in NodeJs that accesses an API that contains information for a specific user. Now, the problem is that there is an access token that needs to be generated that lasts one hour. Instead of of the client going through the process of generating the access token for every call, I want to be able to store the access token somewhere along with the time where it will expire, so that I can prevent unnecessarily going through the entire process every time. What is the best way to do this? I was thinking of making an API that would store the most recent access token for every user, but I want to know if there is a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Redis store to store anything you want so you can have persistent yet lightweight storage for things like this. There are also plugins that allow you to store sessions to Redis, so if you wanted to use session middleware to store the values, you can persist then through Redis.

Comment: Thanks for your response! What are your thoughts on using the Amazon AWS API gateway to store access tokens?

Comment: I guess it depends on your implementation here. I am unsure if the API that you are accessing is your own or someone else's. Who is generating the access token, you or a third party?

Comment: I'm not sure if you are familiar or not with OAuth2.0. I am making an app for Amazon Alexa that needs to access a database that is protected by OAuth. An Access token is good for one hour, and all of it is done in the code for each individual person. It is not my API.